# Searching for the right data structure (add head, swap, remove,...)

Tags: c#, data-structures

I'm searching for a datastructure that provides:

1. adding an Element at the front
2. swapping two elements
3. removing elements
4. when I'm adding an element (not at the last position) the other elements should slip back (like in a queue)
5. access to every Element
6. generic would be nice, but not necessary

The datastructures I found on MSDN do not fulfil my demands

- `List` and `LinkedList` do not provide a swap method
- I could do it with an `ArrayList`, but I guess its horrible inefficient when I'm adding an Element at the front positions (since all Element in behind have to be copied and readded)
- `HashTable` does not provide an order
- `Queue` and `Stack` do not provide swap, random access, ...

I could write my own datastructure, but I dont want to reinvent the wheel, since the .NET library is so huge.

edit:

I need a datastructure that provides similar things like a process-priority-scheduler. The first entry has the highest priority, the last one has the lowest priority. Sometimes I have to change the prority of the Elements (swaping) or completly remove an Element (delete). The Element i added most recently should have the highes priority (thats why I add it at the front position)

Comment: I doubt there's one structure providing a swap method... it is so easy to implement...

Comment: "The good thing about reinventing the wheel is that you can get a round one." - Douglas Crockford

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you are looking for is a heap.

[Wikipedia: Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29)

Heaps are typically used to manage priority and can have the highest priority item on top of the queue and rearrange based on items with different priorities added or removed from the heap.

Here's a generic collection library that has an implementation of an interval heap:

http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/

Answer (score 3):

You really need to figure out how often you are going to be doing those operations, because you listed off an extreme number of them.

Here are my thoughts on your thoughts:

- Implementing a swap method is trivial if you have indexed get/set.
- If you are worried about copying time then reverse your list so you can have cheap inserts at the front, you would need to rewrite a bit of logic to pull it off, but that wouldn't stop using an array as the back end.

Also as a final note, you are certain you don't need automatic sorting of some kind, because that would make this significantly easier.

Comment: +1. Actually you can write an extension method to IList to do that.

Comment: I need a datastructure that provides similar things like a process-priority-scheduler. The first entry has the highest priority, the last one has the lowest priority. Sometimes I have to change the prority of the Elements (swaping) or completly remove an Element (delete). The Element i added most recently should have the highes priority (thats why I add it at the front position)

Comment: @user1826831: A heap is probably your best bet from a raw data structure standpoint, although implementing all of your required functions may require some work, they should all be performant. I am leaving my answer as is since it answers your original question. Feel free to post another if you need more help after looking into heap structures.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer my question. If I could I'd accept both answers. But CLandry has less points than you got. Accepting CLandry's answer maybe motivates him even more ;)

Comment: @user1826831: His answer is more correct, since he includes the data structure *you* were looking for. I just left my answer as is so that if someone else comes along and wants similar results they get some tips even if they aren't doing a priority queue.